# Pou connect game algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, graph, discrete-mathematics

Recently I played a simple game on android called Pou, and one of it's inside games was a connect the dots on the field game. Here is a screenshot to better explain the situation.

[image]

At the beginning of the game you are given n-pairs of dots and you have to connect the same colored ones. While doing this you need to fill the matrix field.

Generating such a field is not a problem, but how can I be sure that it is solvable?

My question would be how can I generate a field that has a solution?
Is this a graph problem? Or some kind of a connectivity problem?

Of course I can always produce a brute force solution, but I am looking for something better

Comment: Would this game be like [Flow Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigduckgames.flow)? (link is to the Android app page) I wouldn't be surprised if there's an algorithm for this similar to union-find (like for mazes).

Comment: Yes it is the same game :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can generate the matrix in such a way that you can be sure it is solvable.

The main idea is as follow. Let say that you need `i` pairs of dots and the matrix is `n by n`

1. Set `i` randomly chosen cells (**start points**) as heads and to each assign a different color.
2. At each iteration for each color move its head randomly (left, right, up, down) into an uncolored cell and color it with `i`-th color. (if there is no legal such moves do not consider this color any more -- that will be the **end point**)
3. When you are finished and there is no uncolored cells you created a legal coloring of the board.
4. If there are some uncolored cells -- it may be quite challenging but for sure doable to modify / extend the coloring you obtained to fill those regions with some color -- the easiest way would be to exclude those regions from the matrix altogether :-)

Some other very loose thoughts:

- each region that consists of more than 2 uncolored cells can be made legal (or at least some part of it) by assigning two additional dots to it;
- you can split your initial `n by n` matrix into smaller rectangular parts and assign to each part some number of dots (proportional to the area) and use the above method -- for sure there will be less uncolored cells when you merge those parts back (on the other hand the puzzle will be bit easier).

**UPDATE**

- once still in phase of *coloring*, if the next move produces a single, isolated cell: chose a different move and if no such move exists stop the coloring process for this color.
- if you want to have a predefined number of dots (or the number close to it), check not only for single isolated cell, but for whole isolated regions. [btw. mind the possibility of coloring a candidate for isolation region by extending its **start point**]
- for relative small `n` you can try using above method(s) until you hit full-coloring (so generate, check if legal, if not: generate again)

**UPDATE II**

If you have time you can try generating colors once at a time, with some probability of stopping, that depends on the length / area of the coloring. So basically just choose a random *uncolored* position and execute the above method. It should be easier to implement.

Comment: Nice way of thinking, but the described algorithm has some uncertainties :(, and can produce not solvable boards a lot of times for greater n-s. But it did give me a different perspective on the whole problem. Thanks ^_^

Comment: @shiroyasha Oh, it was not supposed to be a complete algorithm -- just some directions that can be explored and augmented.

Comment: I know, the above comment was just an explanation why I didn't accept your answer right away. I still think( or at least hope ) that there is a graph algorithm that solves the problem :P